# Merge two anchors from different objects in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to merge/lock two anchor points together in Adobe Illustrator? What I'm trying to achieve is to lock a line segment to a circle so that when I drag the circle, the connected endpoint of the segment moves with the circle but the other endpoint stays in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround: Select with the direct selection tool all anchor points that you are going to move and move them. Leave the fixed end of the line unselected.

It's convenient to drag over the circle and the line with the direct selection tool and then Shift+Click the fixed end of the line to unselect it. You can move with mouse and arrow keys or as well you can goto Object > Transform > Move.